# Node app not sending any data while login 'ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD',

Tags: node.js

I am transferring a node app from one server to another using different domain name.
I have setup everything but I cannot login to the control panel of the app which I have created, I am getting the following error.

```
{ Error: ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD: Field 'origin' doesn't have a default value
at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/var/www/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/pro                                                                   tocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
at Query.ErrorPacket (/var/www/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequen                                                                   ces/Query.js:77:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/www/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Pr                                                                   otocol.js:278:23)
at Parser.write (/var/www/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:7                                                                   6:12)
at Protocol.write (/var/www/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.                                                                   js:38:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:                                                                   91:28)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:                                                                   502:10)
at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/node/anode_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protoc                                                                   ol.js:144:48)
at Connection.query (/var/www/node/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:20                                                                   0:25)
at Object.managerLogin (/var/www/node/node_modules/login/index.js:58:15)
at callbackFunction (/var/www/node/routes/index.js:62:16)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/                                                                   layer.js:95:5)
at next (/var/www/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (/var/www/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/                                                                   layer.js:95:5)
at /var/www/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (/var/www/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:                                                                   330:12)
at next (/var/www/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
at /var/www/node/app.js:55:7
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/                                                                   layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/var/www/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
at /var/www/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/var/www/node/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:                                                                   330:12)
```

code: 'ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD',
  errno: 1364,
  sqlMessage: 'Field \'origin\' doesn\'t have a default value',
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  index: 0,
  sql:
   'INSERT INTO userLog SET `userId` = 2, `token` = \'9d99a1a0-7350-11e9-9671-95abec1f75f6\', `ip` =                                                                    \'\', `browser` = \'\', `isLog` = \'y\', `isValid` = \'y\'' }

Cannot figure this out what is happening,app was running file in the old server.

Answer (score 0):

Debugged it, found it's a mysql bug, edited etc/mysql/my.cnf with `[mysqld]
port = 3306
sql-mode=""`
reloaded mysql, and it worked for me!